# Is it possible to host SPA and static HTMLs together using S3 Static Website Hosting?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, react-router, single-page-application, amazon-route53

I'd like to host client-side rendering SPA (React) and static HTMLs on the same domain using S3 Static Website Hosting.

- SPA is the main application which provides features for logged-in users. SEO is not necessary.
- Static HTMLs are mostly marketing pages for unregistered users / visitors. SEO is important.

Is it possible to host both two on the same domain, like www.example.com for SPA and www.example.com/marketing/ for static HTMLS?

If it's not possible, then what's the best practice for this use case? I'm thinking of using different subdomains for them (www.example.com for marketing and app.example.com for SPA) and separate S3 buckets. It will also make it easy for developers and marketers to edit their own bucket.